# Selenium (python) crashes when scraping many pages (50+)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following script (below) to scrape bond data of off TRACE (link in the code). It's a modified version of this: https://github.com/treatmesubj/FINRABondScrape.

It works on for 50-100 pages, but fails when I try to scrape all ~7,600 pages. The script fails here: `bond = [tablerow.text]` and it throws the following error:

"StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed"

I have added an explicit wait around `tablerows` thinking that some tables take longer to load, but it doesn't seem to be helping as the issue remains. I have tried several other things, but I am out of ideas.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this would be helpful. Also, any tips to speed up the code are welcome. Thanks!

**Update:** the suggestion below from KunduK + increasing `time.sleep(0.8)` to `time.sleep(1.5)` in the `for` loop seem to fixed issue. But, I will wait for a bit before accepting KunduK's answer in case anyone else comes up with a better answer.

```
# TRACE Bond Scraper
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime as dt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
driver.get('http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp')

# Click agree, edit search and submit 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button_blue.agree"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.qs-ui-btn.blue'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.ms-display-switcher.hide'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.button_blue[type=submit]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.rtq-grid-row.rtq-grid-rzrow .rtq-grid-cell-ctn')))
headers = [title.text for title in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    '.rtq-grid-row.rtq-grid-rzrow .rtq-grid-cell-ctn')[1:]]

# Find out the total number of pages to scrape
pg_no = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.qs-pageutil-total > span:nth-child(1)'))).text
pg_no = int(pg_no)

# Scrape tables
bonds = []
for page in range(1, pg_no):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, (f"a.qs-pageutil-btn.on[value='{str(page)}']"))))
    time.sleep(0.8)
    tablerows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.rtq-grid-bd > div.rtq-grid-row')))
    for tablerow in tablerows:
        bond = [tablerow.text]
        bonds.append(bond)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('a.qs-pageutil-next')))).click()
```

Comment: Change to `chrome` instead of  `firefox` hope you will get better output.It worked more than 400 pages however i didn't check further but hope will work for all pages.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I removed the ".on" from this line ```a.qs-pageutil-btn.on[value='{str(page)}']``` and it made the code much more stable. Now it crashes around page ~500.

Comment: So you mean after moved to chrome browser you are getting error after 500 pages?

Comment: I haven't tried Chrome yet, but I think you also suggested (and later deleted) removing ".on"  from the line of code above and that helped me get to page 600 while still using Firefox.

Comment: Try chrome browser hope you will get better output?just give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line from

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, (f"a.qs-pageutil-btn.on[value='{str(page)}']"))))
```

This remove the class `on`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, (f"a.qs-pageutil-btn[value='{str(page)}']"))))
```